# WIF: updated claims not seen by other processes

Tags: wif

I have an STS that logs people in, generates a bunch of claims, loads them into the identity and therefore the principal, and transfers control to my portal app. The portal can see all of the claims via Thread.CurrentPrinciple.Identities. In one circumstance the portal alters two of the claims. After doing this, other methods in the portal can see the updated claims via the same mechanism described above. However, if I transfer control back to the STS, it sees the original claims, not the altered ones, again via Thread.CurrentPrinciple.Identities. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure why there would be a difference... I thought the principal was tied to the session and seen the same by the STS and the relying parties. Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STS and the portal (aka relying party) both have separate cookies and separate sets of claims.  When you browse back from the Portal/rp to the STS and view its identity, you are seeing the STS claims that were added to its local cookie (generated when you first logged into the STS).                                                 When you browse to the Portal you are seeing the claims inside that site's cookie (generated when the STS first posted a WIF token and the Portal's Module intercepted it). Therefore if you modify claims in the portal, they will not effect the claims in the STS cookie.

Comment: Ah so. Thanks for that! Do you know if there is a convention for preserving session-wide information? I thought the cookie was universal, so to speak. If it isn't, I need something that is, and it needs to be secure.

Comment: if you had a universal cookie it would be quickly become un-scalable as your number of claims inside it would grow and grow as you added new sites to your single sign on system. A better pattern is for the STS to issue a small number of generic claims to each RP when it first posts the WIF token to the RP. Then each of your RP's should enrich this token with their own domain specific claims. They can do this via the  ClaimsAuthenticationManager...

Comment: ..If you want state changes made within an RP to be accessible inside the STS, I would probably save the state to the RP's database and implement a web service around it.
 Then when you browse back into the STS call the web service. You could have a central state database, but it leaks out domain knowledge across your federated sites which is not very nice.